# exception in hibernate program

Tags: hibernate, exception

I am following a basic hibernate tutorial. The tutorial program is running & showing output as described in the tutorial but it is showing exception after the output. The program writes, retrieves, & deletes values in/from two MySql database.
Here is the exception:

```
29088 [main] ERROR org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher - Exception executing batch: 
org.hibernate.StaleStateException: Batch update returned unexpected row count from update [0]; actual row count: 0; expected: 1
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.Expectations$BasicExpectation.checkBatched(Expectations.java:85)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.Expectations$BasicExpectation.verifyOutcome(Expectations.java:70)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.BatchingBatcher.checkRowCounts(BatchingBatcher.java:90)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.BatchingBatcher.doExecuteBatch(BatchingBatcher.java:70)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.executeBatch(AbstractBatcher.java:268)
    at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:266)
    at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:172)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:321)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:50)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1027)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:365)
    at org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.commit(JDBCTransaction.java:137)
    at com.hib.Test.deleteUser(Test.java:187)
    at com.hib.Test.main(Test.java:55)
Hibernate: delete from users where id=?
29093 [main] ERROR org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener - Could not synchronize database state with session
org.hibernate.StaleStateException: Batch update returned unexpected row count from update [0]; actual row count: 0; expected: 1
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.Expectations$BasicExpectation.checkBatched(Expectations.java:85)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.Expectations$BasicExpectation.verifyOutcome(Expectations.java:70)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.BatchingBatcher.checkRowCounts(BatchingBatcher.java:90)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.BatchingBatcher.doExecuteBatch(BatchingBatcher.java:70)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.executeBatch(AbstractBatcher.java:268)
    at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:266)
    at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:172)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:321)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:50)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1027)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:365)
    at org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.commit(JDBCTransaction.java:137)
    at com.hib.Test.deleteUser(Test.java:187)
    at com.hib.Test.main(Test.java:55)
org.hibernate.StaleStateException: Batch update returned unexpected row count from update [0]; actual row count: 0; expected: 1
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.Expectations$BasicExpectation.checkBatched(Expectations.java:85)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.Expectations$BasicExpectation.verifyOutcome(Expectations.java:70)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.BatchingBatcher.checkRowCounts(BatchingBatcher.java:90)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.BatchingBatcher.doExecuteBatch(BatchingBatcher.java:70)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.executeBatch(AbstractBatcher.java:268)
    at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:266)
    at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:172)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:321)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:50)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1027)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:365)
    at org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.commit(JDBCTransaction.java:137)
    at com.hib.Test.deleteUser(Test.java:187)
    at com.hib.Test.main(Test.java:55)
```

This is main program.

```
package com.hib;

import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;

public class Test {

 /**
  * @param args
  */
 public static void main(String[] args) {

  Test tst = new Test();

  /**
   * adding records
   */
  tst.addUser("Saranga", "Rath");
  tst.addUser("Isuru", "Sampath");
  tst.addUser("Saranga", "Jaya");
  tst.addUser("Prasanna", "Milinda");

  tst.addTask(1, "Call", "Call Pubudu at 5 PM");
  tst.addTask(1, "Shopping", "Buy some foods for Kity");
  tst.addTask(2, "Email", "Send birthday wish to Pubudu");
  tst.addTask(2, "SMS", "Send message to Dad");
  tst.addTask(2, "Office", "Give a call to Boss");

  /**
   *  retrieving data
   */
  tst.getFullName("Saranga");

  /**
   * full updating records
   */
  User user = new User();
  user.setId(1);
  user.setFirstName("Saranga");
  user.setLastName("Rathnayake");
  tst.updateUser(user);

  /**
   * partial updating records
   */
  tst.updateLastName(3, "Jayamaha");

  /**
   * deleting records
   */
  User user1 = new User();
  user1.setId(4);
  tst.deleteUser(user1);
 }

 private void addUser(String firstName, String lastName) {

  Transaction trns = null;
  Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
  try {
   trns = session.beginTransaction();

   User user = new User();

   user.setFirstName(firstName);
   user.setLastName(lastName);

   session.save(user);

   session.getTransaction().commit();
  } catch (RuntimeException e) {
   if(trns != null){
    trns.rollback();
   }
   e.printStackTrace();
  } finally{
   session.flush();
   session.close();
  }
 }

 private void addTask(int userID, String title, String description) {

  Transaction trns = null;
  Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
  try {
   trns = session.beginTransaction();

   Task task = new Task();

   task.setUserID(userID);
   task.setTitle(title);
   task.setDescription(description);

   session.save(task);

   session.getTransaction().commit();
  } catch (RuntimeException e) {
   if(trns != null){
    trns.rollback();
   }
   e.printStackTrace();
  } finally{
   session.flush();
   session.close();
  }
 }

 private void updateLastName(int id, String lastName) {
  Transaction trns = null;
  Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
  try {
   trns = session.beginTransaction();
   String hqlUpdate = "update User u set u.lastName = :newLastName where u.id = :oldId";
   int updatedEntities = session.createQuery( hqlUpdate )
   .setString( "newLastName", lastName )
   .setInteger( "oldId", id )
   .executeUpdate();

   trns.commit();
  } catch (RuntimeException e) {
   if(trns != null){
    trns.rollback();
   }
   e.printStackTrace();
  } finally{
   session.flush();
   session.close();
  }

 }

 private void updateUser(User user) {
  Transaction trns = null;
  Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
  try {
   trns = session.beginTransaction();

   session.update(user);

   session.getTransaction().commit();
  } catch (RuntimeException e) {
   if(trns != null){
    trns.rollback();
   }
   e.printStackTrace();
  } finally{
   session.flush();
   session.close();
  }
 }

 private void getFullName(String firstName) {
  Transaction trns = null;
  Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
  try {
   trns = session.beginTransaction();
   List<User> users = session.createQuery("from User as u where u.firstName = :firstName")
   .setString( "firstName", firstName )
   .list();
   for (Iterator<User> iter = users.iterator(); iter.hasNext();) {
    User user = iter.next();
    System.out.println(user.getFirstName() +" " + user.getLastName());
   }
   trns.commit();
  } catch (RuntimeException e) {
   if(trns != null){
    trns.rollback();
   }
   e.printStackTrace();
  } finally{
   session.flush();
   session.close();
  }
 }

 private void deleteUser(User user) {
  Transaction trns = null;
  Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
  try {
   trns = session.beginTransaction();

   session.delete(user);

   session.getTransaction().commit();
  } catch (RuntimeException e) {
   if(trns != null){
    trns.rollback();
   }
   e.printStackTrace();
  } finally{
   session.flush();
   session.close();
  }
 }
}
```

HibernateUtil.java

```
package com.hib;

import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;

public class HibernateUtil {
 private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory = buildSessionFactory();
 private static SessionFactory buildSessionFactory() {
  try {
   // Create the SessionFactory from hibernate.cfg.xml
   return new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
  }
  catch (Throwable ex) {
   // Make sure you log the exception, as it might be swallowed
   System.err.println("Initial SessionFactory creation failed." + ex);
   throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
  }
 }
 public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
  return sessionFactory;
 }
}
```

User.java

```
package com.hib;

public class User {
 private Integer id;
 private String firstName;
 private String lastName;

 public Integer getId() {
  return id;
 }
 public void setId(Integer id) {
  this.id = id;
 }
 public String getFirstName() {
  return firstName;
 }
 public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
  this.firstName = firstName;
 }
 public String getLastName() {
  return lastName;
 }
 public void setLastName(String lastName) {
  this.lastName = lastName;
 }
}
```

Task.java

```
package com.hib;

public class Task {

 private Integer id;
 private Integer userID;
 private String title;
 private String description;

 public Integer getId() {
  return id;
 }
 public void setId(Integer id) {
  this.id = id;
 }
 public Integer getUserID() {
  return userID;
 }
 public void setUserID(Integer userID) {
  this.userID = userID;
 }
 public String getTitle() {
  return title;
 }
 public void setTitle(String title) {
  this.title = title;
 }
 public String getDescription() {
  return description;
 }
 public void setDescription(String description) {
  this.description = description;
 }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This exception will occur if you try to delete or update a row that does not exist.
And this is exactly what you do:

```
User user1 = new User();
user1.setId(4);
tst.deleteUser(user1);
```

user1 is never persisted to the DB so how is hibernate supposed to delete it?

BTW: NEVER set an auto generated PK value of an entity yourself, this means trouble.
Also, I noticed that you reference User from Task by using the userID itself in Task. It is valid to relate this way using a Business Key (e.g. unique user email or such) if you want to separate the domains but pointless if you're using the primary key. Instead of `Integer userID`, use `User user` in Task and create a `ManyToOne` with User.